# Why does Pycharm Console do this with my __repr__ method?

Tags: python, repr

```py
class B:
    def __init__(self):
         print('boo!')
         self.a = []

    def __repr__(self):
         print(len(self.a))
         ret = ''
         for a in self.a:
             ret += str(a)
         return ret
```

The following is copy pasted from the Pycharm Console using python 3.8.6 and IPython 7.31.0:

```
>>> b = B()
boo!
0
0
>> b
Out[4]: 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
>> 2 + 3
Out[5]: 5
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

This does not happen in python REPL or iPython running in the cmd (see comments).

Why is this happening?

Comment: From here `print(len(self.a))`

Comment: Maybe because the python shell is trying to show you `b`. If you run this as standalone script you do not get the 0 output.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: The answer is in the code: `#when an instance is created in console, this method is also called`

Comment: This is odd and I couldn't figure out 'why' yet, but I think it must be a bug in the pycharm console (which I think you are using). It is only in the pycharm console that I could replicate this. Neither the regular python REPL (3.8.6), which you get when typing 'python' in the cmd, nor ipython (7.31.0), which you can get by typing 'ipython' in the cmd (and which is used by the pycharm console) show this behaviour. Also removing the calls to print from .__repr__ made this behaviour disappear.. If any one has more information, I would also be very intersted in it.

Comment: @Stryder YES!! I am using Pycharm. Can't reproduce it on regular python either.

Comment: @EricJin I am using python 3.9.6 under pycharm.

Comment: @AveryL, I hope you don't mind but i submitted an edit, which will hopefully be approved, and would change your question to be much more specific to the real problem (pycharm console).

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's *wrong* for PyCharm to call `__repr__` in this case, but it's definitely *odd*. Does it really call `__repr__` every time, even if you did something like `[B() for _ in range(10000)]`?

Comment: @chepner, I have no idea what it's like to have your kind of reputation, but I submitted an edit to this question that shows clearly how (extremely) odd this behaviour is. If there is any chance that you can approve it, it may spark even more interest in this. :)

Comment: @chepner  Turned out that it really called __repr__ every time

Comment: (I should have said something like `x = [B() for _ in range(10000)]`; it's clearly reasonable to call `__repr__` for each object if the list is being displayed.)

Answer (score 0):

You're only showing and using `B` in your code, so we'll use just that.

```py
class B:
    def __init__(self):
         print('boo!')
         self.a = []

    def add_a(self, a):
         self.a.append(a)

    def __repr__(self):
         print(len(self.a))
         ret = ''
         for a in self.a:
             ret += str(a)
         return ret
```

When you run just `B()` (a [call expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls)), this is the sequence of things that happens (in python and ipython):

1. create new instance with `__new__` (inherited from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object))
2. initialise the instance with `__init__`, which prints `boo!` and sets the `a` attribute to an empty list `[]`
3. display the instance you've just created with `__repr__`, which in your case:

- prints `0`, the length of `a` attribute
- set a local `ret` variable to `''`
- iterates through the `a` attribute which is empty
- returns returns `''` from `ret`

However, step 3. applies only to running expressions `B()`, the python interactive shell runs the expression and displays their result.

The `b = B()` [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) should not trigger a "display result" event (and will not in python, IDLE or ipython).

Comment: You are saying that the b = B() statement will not run step 3. And it really shouldn't, but have you tried to run that in the pycharm console? It is definitely using the __repr__ method in strange ways and I can replicate using just this: `class Klass:
    def __repr__(self):
        print("1")
        return 'nothing' `

Comment: I don't know about PyCharm, but statements don't need displaying and should not call `__repr__`.

Comment: I assume that when I run B() the method __repr()__ is called, but why?@ljmc

Comment: `B()` is an really a [call expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), `b = B()` is a simple [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). The interactive python shell considers that expressions should be displayed via [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) which uses the `__repr__` dunder method.